# Not able to go and click on submenus in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate a website where in i am required to click on submenu KPI.

KPI is a sub-child of Performance

For that i am using cy.trigger(mouseenter}

However the problem is no matter i use mouseenter or mouseover the focus is not going on child elements.

Even the chaining of commands is  not working.

There is one more problem with the website, except this link all the links are clickable.

Hence for clicking the submenus,the only option is to focus on that link.

What is the best way to find these elements.
Below are the screenshots of sample page and html code.

**HTML Screenshot**

[image]

**UI Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hey @Manish B have you tried triggering the mouse event with `cy.get()`. For eg. `cy.get('li#menu_performance_Configure').trigger('mousedown', { button: 0 })`. This will simulate mouse left click on the element.

Comment: Could you share the full code?

Comment: @konekoya
do u want me to share the html code

Comment: Nothing is working
Tried following commands
cy.get("a").contains("Performance").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger('mouseover')
cy.get("a").contains("Performance").trigger("mouseenter").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger('mouseover')
cy.get("a").contains("Performance").trigger("mouseover").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger("mouseover")

Comment: Right, but please edit your Post and place them in a JS code block like: ```javascript ${your_code_here}```

Comment: javascript
{
cy.get("a").contains("Performance").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger('mouseover') cy.get("a").contains("Performance").trigger("mouseenter").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger('mouseover') cy.get("a").contains("Performance").trigger("mouseover").find("li#menu_performance_Configure").trigger("mouseover")
}